# Users, subusers, and assigning subuser to multiple users

Tags: 7, users

I want the following functionality in Drupal 7: Create a few parent users/business representatives (e.g. Google, Microsoft); these business representatives will add their business profile, and add employees of that specific company, add/edit/delete them. An employee can be from multiple companies and all business representatives can edit/delete employee's profiles.
Employees can also log in, and manage their own profiles.

Which modules should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Subuser](http://drupal.org/project/subuser) module to create subusers and a [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module to create user profiles for every user.